# Retrieve all answers in an array from a MySQL JSON column

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I am using MySQL 5.7 and currently have a JSON column with data like this:

```json
{"quiz_scores":[{"quiz_date":1697706210448,"symptom_improvement_score":false,"coping_skill_acquisition_score":true,"increased_self_awareness_score":true,"account_age_in_days":2197},{"quiz_date":1697706316322,"symptom_improvement_score":false,"coping_skill_acquisition_score":false,"increased_self_awareness_score":false,"account_age_in_days":2197},{"quiz_date":1697706347304,"symptom_improvement_score":true,"coping_skill_acquisition_score":true,"increased_self_awareness_score":true,"account_age_in_days":2197},{"quiz_date":1698229246050,"symptom_improvement_score":true,"coping_skill_acquisition_score":false,"increased_self_awareness_score":true,"account_age_in_days":2203},{"quiz_date":1698320799172,"symptom_improvement_score":true,"coping_skill_acquisition_score":true,"increased_self_awareness_score":true,"account_age_in_days":2204}]}
```

I can extract the latest result with some conditions using `json_length` and subtracting one.

```sql
select 
    sp.user_uuid, 
    sp.stub,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`,CONCAT("$.quiz_scores[",JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value` ->> '$.quiz_scores')-1,"].quiz_date")) /1000) as quiz_date,
    JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`,CONCAT("$.quiz_scores[",JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value` ->> '$.quiz_scores')-1,"].account_age_in_days")) as account_age_in_days
from series_progress sp
where sp.stub in ('questionnaire_my_progress')
and JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`,CONCAT("$.quiz_scores[",JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value` ->> '$.quiz_scores')-1,"].symptom_improvement_score")) = true
and JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`,CONCAT("$.quiz_scores[",JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value` ->> '$.quiz_scores')-1,"].coping_skill_acquisition_score")) = true
and JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`,CONCAT("$.quiz_scores[",JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value` ->> '$.quiz_scores')-1,"].increased_self_awareness_score")) = true
and JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`,CONCAT("$.quiz_scores[",JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value` ->> '$.quiz_scores')-1,"].account_age_in_days")) > 1
```

What I would like to do, instead of only checking the latest score, but get all scores from the JSON. It sounds like `JSON_TABLE` in MySQL 8 may do the job, is there a way in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing these data as JSON? It seems like it makes all your queries much harder. Wouldn't the queries be easier if you stored the data in normal rows and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, make a little table with ordinal numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers ( n INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO numbers (n) VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

This table doesn't have to have all integers up to 2<sup>32</sup>, but it needs at least as many as the maximum length of JSON array you need to support.

Then you can cross-join this to your table with JSON and get every element from a JSON array.

```
SELECT
  t.user_uuid,
  t.stub,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(t.quiz_score->>'$.quiz_date'/1000) AS quiz_date,
  t.quiz_score->>'$.account_age_in_days' AS account_age_in_days
FROM (
  SELECT
    sp.user_uuid, 
    sp.stub,
    JSON_EXTRACT(sp.`value`, CONCAT('$.quiz_scores[',n.n,']')) AS quiz_score
  FROM series_progress AS sp
  CROSS JOIN numbers AS n
  WHERE n.n < JSON_LENGTH(sp.`value`->'$.quiz_scores')
  AND sp.stub IN ('questionnaire_my_progress')
) AS t
WHERE t.quiz_score->>'$.symptom_improvement_score' = true
  AND t.quiz_score->>'$.coping_skill_acquisition_score' = true
  AND t.quiz_score->>'$.increased_self_awareness_score' = true
  AND t.quiz_score->>'$.account_age_in_days' > 1;
```

Honestly, workarounds like this make it apparent that JSON is not actually an efficient idea when you need to use SQL predicates to search or sort fields within a JSON document.

---

Re your comment:

The problem you are facing is that MySQL doesn't convert JSON booleans to SQL booleans transparently. A JSON boolean value like `true` or `false` is returned as binary strings `'true'` or `'false'`, whereas MySQL booleans are unsigned integers 1 and 0 respectively.

We can see this in the MySQL client when we run with the `--column-type-info` option:

```
mysql> set @j = '{"f1": true, "f2": false}';

mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract(@j, "$.f1")) as f1;
Field   1:  `f1`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONG_BLOB
Collation:  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (255)
Length:     4294967295
Max_length: 4
Decimals:   31
Flags:      BINARY 

+------+
| f1   |
+------+
| true |
+------+
```

When you compare this string to the SQL `true` (which is really the integer 1), it compels MySQL to try to case the binary string `'true'` to a comparable numeric value. MySQL casts strings to numeric values by examining any leading digits, and if there are no leading digits, it assumes the numeric value of the string is 0. So both `'true'` and `'false'` are cast to 0 (false).

This is related to this bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=99237 The workaround for that bug is to use a new MySQL 8.0 function JSON_VALUE() to extract the boolean *and* cast it to an unsigned value explicitly.  You'd do something like:

```
WHERE ...
  JSON_VALUE(t.quiz_score, '$.coping_skill_acquisition_score' RETURNING UNSIGNED) = true
```

But of course JSON_VALUE() isn't implemented in MySQL 5.7.

You can work around this in your case by comparing the extracted value to the *string* `'true'` instead of the boolean literal `true`.

```
WHERE t.quiz_score->>'$.symptom_improvement_score' = 'true'
  AND t.quiz_score->>'$.coping_skill_acquisition_score' = 'true'
  AND t.quiz_score->>'$.increased_self_awareness_score' = 'true'
```

This is yet another example of why using JSON for relational data is a terrible idea. You end up spending a lot of time studying all the intricate semantics of type casting to work around these sorts of bugs.

---

Testing this further, I discovered that JSON booleans *are* cast properly if you *don't* use the JSON unquoting. By using `->>` you made the boolean cast to the binary string. But if you had used `->` then the JSON boolean can implicitly cast to an SQL boolean.

The following works, using non-unquoted JSON extraction and comparing to SQL boolean literals:

```
WHERE t.quiz_score->'$.symptom_improvement_score' = true
  AND t.quiz_score->'$.coping_skill_acquisition_score' = true
  AND t.quiz_score->'$.increased_self_awareness_score' = true
```

More and more layers of confusing semantics!

Comment: Thanks @Bill Karwin, got an issue though. If i add `t.quiz_score->>'$.coping_skill_acquisition_score' AS coping_skill_acquisition_score,` to the outer select. Then add the WHERE clause `WHERE t.quiz_score->>'$.coping_skill_acquisition_score' = true` i would expect all results would be true for that column, it is returning no results, if i change it to false it returns 20 results of which 6 are false, the rest true.

Comment: thanks that got it, agree about using JSON for relational data. It was not designed as a first party feature and got shoe horned in to existing functionality.

Comment: i am upgrading to mysql 8, am i correct in thinking this query can be simplified using JSON_TABLE?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the type of task that JSON_TABLE() is meant to be used to solve. You should read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) and the [blog](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/) introducing it, and give it a try. If you get stuck, post a new question showing an example of what you are trying, show what you tried even if it didn't work, and what you want as a result.